# How is null implemented in Java?

Tags: java

I know that null is not a data type.

But `null` can be only assigned for any type of `Object` and `String`.

Example:

```
Object o = null; // it tells that null is an object
String b = null; // it tells that null is of string type
```

Here `null` can be assigned to both an `Object` and a `String`, but if I want to put assign any object into String we have to use type cast. but for null there is no type case.
something like the following

```
String b =(String) o;
```

Thats why I have doubt that which type of data type is null. How null can be assigned to any object or any String. How is `null` implemented in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `null` reference and keyword are Java built-in constructs and are treated specially by the compiler. The compiler then emits the corresponding bytecode instructions depending on the context which `null` is used in.

Note that this behavior is different from older languages such as C or C++03 where NULL pointer was simply a zero constant.

Comment: how null can be assigned to any type of Object?

Comment: @Deepakkk - because the JLS says it can.

Comment: @Deepakkk: Edited to clarify a bit, hopefully it makes better sense for you now

Comment: Doesn't "built-in constructs and are treated specially by the compiler" answer your question?

Comment: Actually, there is only one context in which `null` can be used: as an expression of any reference type (e.g. assigning to a reference variable, passing as a reference parameter, casting to a reference type, comparing to a reference variable). There is no special-casing by the compiler here for different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object o = null; // it tells that null is an object
String b = null; // it tells that null is of string type
```

Neither of those comments is correct. All that's happening here is that references are being set to null.