# How does Java store a null?

Tags: java, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)
>   [How is null implemented in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729702/how-is-null-implemented-in-java)

Suppose I say

```
String x = null;
```

How is this null stored internally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this question:
[What is null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)
Basically, usually stored as 0's same as C++ but this can be implementation-specific and so you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

As per [java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) it is a sort of literal.

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null,
>   which has no name. Because the null type has no name, it is impossible
>   to declare a variable of the null type or to cast to the null type.
>   The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null
>   type. The null reference can always be cast to any reference type. In
>   practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend
>   that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference
>   type.

Answer (score 2):

In Java the runtime must ensure that all heap-allocated memory is zeroed out before the pointer to the block is exposed to the Java code. The all-zeroes block will be interpreted as the initial values of the instance fields. This pretty much guarantees that `null` will be implemented as a zero value in any JVM implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The `null` value is stored in the variable `x`.